# How to make a function which takes arguments of the values from another function?

Tags: r, arrays, function

Here is my sample code:

```
library(Metrics)
   sample <- function(a,b) {
    x <- 1/a
    y <- b

    fit <- lm(y~x)
    }

    error <- function(a,e){
    mae <- mae(a,e)
    rae <- rmse(a,e)
    }
```

My goal is to insert the `error` function inside the `sample` function, where `error` function will take arguments of the observed and predicted values from the lm model within the `sample` function.

Thank You for the responses and improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this is what you're after. You can just call another function inside a function, just make sure you assign outputs properly, and make sure that the function you're calling from the other function is defined first in the script.

```r
library(Metrics)

error <- function(a,e){
  mae <- mae(a,e)
  rae <- rmse(a,e)
  return(**be specific here**) #define what is handed back to the other function
}

sample <- function(a,b) {
  x <- 1/a
  y <- b

  fit <- lm(y~x)

  erroroutput=error(a=a, e=fit$effects) #define, what from the fit-output should be passed to the error function
  return(erroroutput) #I guess the result from the error function should be returned?
}
```

Comment: I will try it immediately. I am recently learning how to program using R for our statistics, and this would be a great help. Thank You.